# Can we ask questions based on ROM hacks or randomizers?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

[This question is the one in question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/333113/in-which-city-i-can-catch-fire-type-pokemon-in-ash-grey), it being a ROM hack of FireRed.

This is not an officially released game, but a modified version of an official game.

My question also extends to hacks like randomizers such as [Zelda: Link to the Past](https://alttpr.com/en).

Is this type of question allowed, based on these games not being officially released?

Comment: Do we allow questions about obvious intellectual property theft, such as Pixelmon? I'd say we treat ROM hacks and randomizers the same way, which is to allow them.

Comment: We allow questions about mods, 'ROM hacks' arent any different, just a different name for the same thing, and Randomizers are just a popular subgenre of mods/ROM hacks. On legality issues: Most ROM hacks are distributed as ips patch files with wholly original code, avoiding any legality issues regarding redistributing copyrighted works. tbh I'm struggling to see any reason why we *wouldn't* allow them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, asking questions about these types of games is perfectly fine, as long as you're not asking how to acquire hacks/ROMs. We've even got a tag for the [zelda-a-link-to-the-past-randomizer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-a-link-to-the-past-randomizer) with a well-received question already. It's basically just a mod on the original game, and we've accepted mod questions for a long time.